# How to multiply the pseudo-inverse (from SVD) of every column in a matrix by another vector in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a matrix `H` of size, for example, `4 x 4`, and a vector `x` of size `4 x 1`, I need to multiply the inverse of each column in `H` by the vector `x` and put the output in a vector.

for example, suppose I have the matrix `H`:

```
H =

   0.4657 + 0.4162j  -0.4419 + 0.0632j  -1.1432 - 0.2708j   0.3158 + 0.3111j
   0.1696 - 0.5686j  -0.2734 - 0.8657j  -0.1369 - 0.2353j  -1.2032 + 0.4967j
   0.5696 + 0.1004j  -0.1986 - 1.1916j   0.3550 - 0.9894j   0.5620 + 0.4882j
  -0.2774 - 0.7854j  -0.8613 - 0.7542j   0.4103 + 0.5212j  -0.4590 + 0.8673j
```

and vector x :

```
x =

   0.3572 + 0.2677i
  -0.4189 + 0.8054i
  -0.7021 + 0.9831i
   0.0757 + 1.1424i
```

In MATLAB, I did it straightforward as below:

```
clear all; clc 

    H = [0.4657 + 0.4162i,  -0.4419 + 0.0632i,  -1.1432 - 0.2708i,   0.3158 + 0.3111i;
    0.1696 - 0.5686i,  -0.2734 - 0.8657i,  -0.1369 - 0.2353i,  -1.2032 + 0.4967i;
    0.5696 + 0.1004i,  -0.1986 - 1.1916i,   0.3550 - 0.9894i,   0.5620 + 0.4882i;
    0.5696 + 0.1004i,  -0.1986 - 1.1916i,   0.3550 - 0.9894i,   0.5620 + 0.4882i]

    x = [0.3572 + 0.2677i;
      -0.4189 + 0.8054i;
      -0.7021 + 0.9831i;
       0.0757 + 1.1424i]
    xn = [];
    for yy = 1 : size(H, 2)
         nn = H(:,yy); 
         x2= pinv(nn).*x;
         X3 = [xn x2];
    end
```

as result, vector `X3 = [-0.8307 + 0.1398i,  -0.7071 - 0.7071i,  -0.4029 - 0.1116i,   0.6284 - 0.1415i]`

Now, I try to do the same thing in python but I get an error, as below:

```
import numpy as np

H  = [[0.4657 + 0.4162i,  -0.4419 + 0.0632i,  -1.1432 - 0.2708i,   0.3158 + 0.3111i],
    [0.1696 - 0.5686i,  -0.2734 - 0.8657i,  -0.1369 - 0.2353i,  -1.2032 + 0.4967i],
    [0.5696 + 0.1004i,  -0.1986 - 1.1916i,   0.3550 - 0.9894i,   0.5620 + 0.4882i],
    [0.5696 + 0.1004i,  -0.1986 - 1.1916i,   0.3550 - 0.9894i,   0.5620 + 0.4882i]]
x = [[0.3572 + 0.2677j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j]] 

X3 = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for i in range(4): 
    X3 = np.linalg.pinv(h[:,i]) @ y
```

but, `X3` is giving an error in that case! it doesn't give the expected results.

thank you in advance

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need the pseudo inverse of every colum? Rather than taking the inverse of H?

Comment: @sgillen , Hmmm. in our field we usually use inverse of every column to avoid inverse the noise which has negative effect on the signal transmission. when inversing H, the noise will be inversed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, imaginary in Python is `j`. Use `numpy.array()` and reshape before passing into `pinv()`:

```
import numpy as np

H  = np.array([[0.4657 + 0.4162j,  -0.4419 + 0.0632j,  -1.1432 - 0.2708j,   0.3158 + 0.3111j],
    [0.1696 - 0.5686j,  -0.2734 - 0.8657j,  -0.1369 - 0.2353j,  -1.2032 + 0.4967j],
    [0.5696 + 0.1004j,  -0.1986 - 1.1916j,   0.3550 - 0.9894j,   0.5620 + 0.4882j],
    [0.5696 + 0.1004j,  -0.1986 - 1.1916j,   0.3550 - 0.9894j,   0.5620 + 0.4882j]])

x = np.array([[0.3572 + 0.2677j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j]])

X3 = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for j in range(4): 
    X3[:,j] = np.linalg.pinv(H[:,j].reshape(-1,1)).dot(x)
```

Comment: why did you use the reshape before passing into pinv() ? If you have checked the code in MATLAB, would that give the same results ? .. I think it's different, is n't it?

Comment: I used reshape because otherwise you will get an error. `H[:,j]` is a slice of the matrix and in python this would be an array with second empty dimension `(4,)`. To understand this type `H[:,0].shape` and then `H[:,0].reshape(-1,1).shape`. So you need to reshape it into a vector with dimensions `(4,1)` and then `np.pinv()` will not throw any error.